# Comments in text file being read for Java

Tags: java, comments

When writing a program in Java, and you want to read a file, is there a way the USER can have the program completely ignore certain lines or characters by making the certain file's line or character into more of a 'comment'? Just as a programmer can use '//' or '/* */' while programming.

Comment: Yes, there are many ways. Have you tried something?

Comment: Is your code reading the file? If so, you can implement it yourself.

Comment: not printing them to the user doesn't suffice ?

Comment: Sure, assuming that the program is smart enough to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip the lines that start with a certain pattern (e.g. '//' or '#').

There's an example on how to read a file in Java line by line here: http://www.roseindia.net/Java/beginners/java-read-file-line-by-line.shtml

You can change the while-loop like this:

```
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
  if (!strLine.startWith("#"))
    System.out.println (strLine);
}
```

In this example lines starting with '#' will not get printed.

Comment: I guess that's as close as it gets.. Thanks!

Comment: You can of course extend/customize this to your needs. If this helped, then you can accept the answer :).

Answer (score 0):

If it is a properties file format and you are using `Properties` to read it, you can use the pound character.  Otherwise, no, you will need to implement something yourself.

```
my.prop1=val1
#some comment
my.prop2=val2
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  If program uses code like this to read lines from the file:

```
BufferedReader reader = 
    new BufferedReader (
        new InputStreamReader (new FileInputStream (inputFile)));

String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine ()) != null)
{
    if (line.startWith ("#") || line.trim ().isEmpty ())
        continue; // Ignore the line

    // Process the line
}
```

User can mark some lines as comments by prefixing them with pound ('#') character.

Answer (score 0):

this depends on what you want to accomplish
if you simply want to transform the new file, then you can use `BufferedReader reader` to read the file line by line and then check each line to see if it meet some criteria,
and take the necessary action 
like `if (line.startWith ("#") || line.trim ().isEmpty ())` otherwise it will be better to use standard libraries to perform operations on your file, such as compressing the file, changing the file to a different format etc